# SSRS Parameter update field

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder, reportparameter

I need to update parameter names in my Report based on "Language" parameter value.
So, when i choose one language, other parameter names should change.

Is it possible? If yes, is it possible from Report Builder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by **Parameter Names** you mean the values displayed, then yes you can have one parameter selection update another. A typical example would be to choose a **country** in one parameter and then choose a **city** from that country in a second parameter. It's called **Cascading Parameters**.

The basic idea is that each parameter will be based on a query and each query will use the previous parameter.

Country dataset for @COUNTRIES parameter:

```
SELECT COUNTRY FROM COUNTRIES
```

City dataset based on other parameter for @CITIES parameter:

```
SELECT CITY FROM CITIES WHERE COUNTRY IN (@COUNTRIES)
```

[Here's some more information from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255197.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, but what i need is to change parameter name, not value for that parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the other parameter names based on one parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to update parameter name, as parameters are mapped in dataset from the query or stored procedure running on the back end, so there is no such way to update that query/stored procedure parameter name once the SSRS report is running.